someone know how to perform a Random Intercept Item Factor Analysis (RIIFA) in R?
I need to performe a Random Intercept Item Factor Analysis (RIIFA) but I don't if there is a library or a function dedicated to this type of factor analysis
I search in google, scholar, scopus etc. I read some papers but there is no code

According to this page 17 and  this you're looking for R lavaan package.
